# Selectable text in wpf

Tags: wpf, selectable, selectall

I am trying to render a WPF window that has lots of labels, textboxes, textblocks which are binding to data.
I want to be able to select by mouse all the data or part of the data on the window.
Is there a simple way in WPF to do that?
Should I use page instead of window?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to select text across multiple TextBox, Labels and TextBlocks in WPF.

Each control will hold selection specifically to itself so you must use another approach that will enable you to select the text.

I can think of one rudimentary way to achieve this is to have a very small button beside each TextBox,TextBlock, etc. that you wish to select and this button will perform a string concatenation of the associated text to the clipboard.

The result is that you have all the strings you wish to select in your clipboard ready to paste to wherever you like.

Good luck.